# Amazon Basics USB Ethernet adapter loses connection after ~24 hours

Tags: networking, usb, network-manager, 17.04, ethernet

I've been having issues with an Amazon Basics Gigabit Ethernet adapter with Ubuntu 17.04.  For reference, `lsusb` reports it as `ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet`.

It would seem that after approximately 24 hours of uptime (I haven't measured it exactly, but it seems pretty consistent) the network connection via the adapter just kind of hangs.  Any applications I have that use the network seem to just stop receiving packets.  The network in general is still working, because other Ethernet-connected devices I have still work, and I'm fairly sure the issue is with this adapter specifically, since I started seeing it right after I installed it.

I am able to work around this by disabling, and then re-enabling network via the network indicator, but I'd prefer if I didn't have to do that once a day.  Does anyone know a solution to this issue?

Comment: That is an old adapter and my advice is to install the driver provided by asix. There is a ppa here - https://launchpad.net/ax88179 it seems it is just a simple package and old so you may need to either download the .deb and / or install the driver manually - see https://blog.pregos.info/2014/02/21/howto-asix-ax88179-usb-3-0-gigabit-ethernet-unter-ubuntu-13-10/ ( google translate the page if needed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, whatever the problem was, it seems to have been fixed after upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10.  Haven't noticed any issues with the adapter since then.